# Why am I not able to access the inner div and input element contained in div in the following scenario?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors, jquery

I'm having a very length web page HTML. For your reference I'm putting below a representative HTML. Like this HTML all other HTML is there on my webpage.

```
<tr class="bulkop">
  <td valign="middle">
    <p class="custom-form">
      <div class="ez-checkbox">
        <input id="practice_6_189" class="custom-check ez-hide" type="checkbox" onchange="enable_text_boxes('practice_6_189')" value="189" name="practice_topics_6[]">
      </div>
      <label>Enviornmetal Chemistry</label>
      <input type="hidden" value="Enviornmetal Chemistry" name="topic_names[189]">
    </p>
  </td>
  <td valign="middle">
    <em>Total 150</em>
    <input id="practice_6_189_1" class="mini" type="text" disabled="" value="" maxlength="3" name="practice_6_189_1">
    <input type="hidden" value="150" name="practice_available_questions_6_189_1">
  </td>
  <td valign="middle">
    <em>Total 81</em>
    <input id="practice_6_189_2" class="mini" type="text" disabled="" value="" maxlength="3" name="practice_6_189_2">
    <input type="hidden" value="81" name="practice_available_questions_6_189_2">
  </td>
  <td valign="middle">
    <em>Total 122</em>
    <input id="practice_6_189_3" class="mini" type="text" disabled="" value="" maxlength="3" name="practice_6_189_3">
    <input type="hidden" value="122" name="practice_available_questions_6_189_3">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="bulkop">
  <td valign="middle">
    <p class="custom-form">
      <div class="ez-checkbox">
        <input id="practice_6_190" class="custom-check ez-hide" type="checkbox" onchange="enable_text_boxes('practice_6_190')" value="190" name="practice_topics_6[]">
      </div>
      <label>Structure of Atom</label>
      <input type="hidden" value="Structure of Atom" name="topic_names[190]">
    </p>
  </td>
  <td valign="middle">
    <em>Total 810</em>
    <input id="practice_6_190_1" class="mini" type="text" disabled="" value="" maxlength="3" name="practice_6_190_1">
    <input type="hidden" value="810" name="practice_available_questions_6_190_1">
  </td>
  <td valign="middle">
    <em>Total 394</em>
    <input id="practice_6_190_2" class="mini" type="text" disabled="" value="" maxlength="3" name="practice_6_190_2">
    <input type="hidden" value="394" name="practice_available_questions_6_190_2">
  </td>
  <td valign="middle">
    <em>Total 321</em>
    <input id="practice_6_190_3" class="mini" type="text" disabled="" value="" maxlength="3" name="practice_6_190_3">
    <input type="hidden" value="321" name="practice_available_questions_6_190_3">
  </td>
</tr>
```

For your reference I've just put in two `<tr>` tags. Actually there are many such `<tr>` my HTML is having. Now I want to access the inner div and the input contained in the div for all the `<tr>` tags present in a page. For that I wrote follwoing jQuery but not able to apply the said class to div as well as input present inside div. I'm not getting any error in the console. Can you correct me if I'm going in wrong way in manipulating the HTML elements? Thanks in advance. My jQuery function code is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function()  { 
$("#ckbCheckAll").click(function () {   

    $('tr .bulkop td p div .ez-checkbox').toggleClass("ez-checked", this.checked);
    $('tr .bulkop td p div .ez-checkbox input').toggleClass("ez-checked", this.checked);

    var id_checkboxes = $('tr .bulkop td p div .ez-checkbox input').map(function() {
      return this.id;
    }).get();
    for (var i = 0; i < id_checkboxes.length; i++) {
      toggle_question_count('#'+id_checkboxes[i]);
    }    
  });
});
```

I'm not able to toggle the classes. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

because you can't have a `<div>` inside a `<p>`  it's invalid markup.... see?? [image]

Comment: You have different html.

Comment: @FLCL ofcourse the html is different... if you try to nest a `<div>` tag inside a `<p>`  tag.. the browser will automatically  close the `<p>` tag.. take a look at this... http://jsfiddle.net/4w7Mn/

Answer (score 0):

Correct selector is not 'tr.bulkop td p div.ez-checkbox', but 'tr.bulkop td p div.ez-checkbox'. It because of difference between specifying and children selectors: removing spaces between tag name and class will make selector to find element with this tag name and class.